# Android:Problems with listview when I scroll the list and is disordered

Tags: android, listview, view, adapter, helper

*I have an adapter for a ListView which dynamically gets relative layouts to display images and text loaded into the Adapter.
The problem is that when I scroll in its entirety, the Listview is ordered incorrectly. I tried using ViewHolder but that has not solved the problem.
I wonder if there is any other way to do it. Or integer Listview load without execute code that once adapter has already been loaded list.
The main problem is that the images of the other RelativeLayout layouts appear in the wrong list.*

**Now The problem I have now is that when you scroll through the list slowly shows fine, but if the scroll in the list is fast elements are dislodged. As if not process fast enough position parameter. public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)**

Comment: Please provide some relevant code...

Comment: Very confusing question. Let us know what you've tried

Comment: Without seeing any code, I'd guess that it's probably something to do with the way that the list reuses views.  Review how you're using the `convertView` parameter as well as (if relevant) `getViewType` and `getItemViewType`. But as Ole says, post some code and you'll get a more useful response.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ListAdapter`'s `getView()`; make sure that if `convertView` is null that you are creating it. In both cases you want to update `convertView` with new data, otherwise you'll have these issues (as Android will recycle those views but not update them).